# managing permission on Delta lake view in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have a delta lake table created in azure databricks. And for this table I have created different views which basically contain data of different customers. These customers are there in my Azure AAD as gues users and I have created the SCIM pipeline to pull AAD users to Databricks workspace.

I would like my customer to access their view and at the same time enable them to query their view. What permission should I give and at what level so that once they log in to the databricks workspace. they should be able to see only their view and create a SQL warehouse to query .

Comment: are you using Unity Catalog?

Comment: yes I am using Unity catalog

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `SELECT` permission to users/groups ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-privileges/privileges#select)) together with corresponding `USE CATALOG` and `USE SCHEMA`. Documentation also says following:

> **The owner of a view must have the ability to read the tables and views referenced in the view**. *A reader of a view does not need the ability to read the tables and views referenced in the view, unless they are using a cluster with single user access mode*.

Comment: So if i use a shared cluster and I want my user to query their view only without looking into other tables or views.. I will provide the above you mentioned on the data side and on Cluster side I should give them permission Can Restart.. so that they can spin up a notebook in shared workspace and attach and start the shared cluster. Is that correct? can you confirm this?

Comment: To be able to read data you just need "Can Attach". "Can Restart" is required if they want to terminate the cluster. But you mentioned SQL warehouses - then it will work out of the box, and probably will be more efficient

Comment: I tried that, it does nt work. They dont see the cluster on top right, just see the start Warehouse pro option. They are able to start the already created cluster but on View it says cant view data without an active cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity Catalog you can use the GRANT command to give certain privileges to the user and it can be provided on all Objects, Tables, Views, schema, and many more for your use case you can write this command to give access or not to the user.

GRANT SELECT ON VIEW TO @user This way to grant DENY, and REVOKE privileges to any users with the help of unity Catalog.

P.S. You can also create groups to have better governance like admin group read access.

For further reference, you can look into Databricks Docs

https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-privileges/index.html

Comment: Please check I dont think one can grant read permission to a view without giving read access to a table in Databricks. would appreciate if you can check and confirm that